# Django display dependent dropdown of 2 tables using jquery

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have two tables and related it using foreign key. I want to display the values of tables using jquery.

My views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from sampleapp.models import *
from django.conf import settings
import os
def personal(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        v1=request.POST.get('category1')
        categoryquiz(category=v1).save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/personal')
    else:
        return render(request,'first.html')
def sectional(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        v2=request.POST.get('drop1')
        v3=request.POST.get('section1')
        sectionquiz(var1_id=v2,section=v3).save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/show')
    else:
        st=categoryquiz.objects.all()
        return render(request,'second.html',{'st':st})
def show(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        sectionquiz(var1_id=v5,section=v5).save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/show')
    else:
        st=categoryquiz.objects.all()
        s=sectionquiz.objects.all()
        return render(request,"list.html",{'st':st,'s':s})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class categoryquiz(models.Model):
    category=models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
class sectionquiz(models.Model):
    var1=models.ForeignKey(categoryquiz)
    section=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.var.name
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#drop1').on('change', function() { 
            alert($("#drop1").val()); 
            $

});
});
</script>
<body>
category:<select id="drop1">
{% for i in st %}
<option value={{i.id}}>{{i.category}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
section:<select id="drop2">
{% for i in s %}
<option value={{i.id}}>{{i.section}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<table id="tab1">
{% for i in s %}
<tr>
 <td> {{i.var1.category}}</td>
  <td>{{i.section}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<div id="div1">
</div>
</html>
```

In my html file i can display the values of two tables separately. Also in combined form. I just want to display it using jquery. When I select category the corresponding sectioned should be displayed in other dropdown or text box.

help me to proceed..

Comment: You're missing something.. what's the question? It would be helpful to show what you're getting and what you're expecting.

Comment: In models I declared 2 tables, one for category and another for section and related using foreign key. Category eg. C, C++... Section eg. For c- loop, functions.. For C++- inheritance,templates.. I want jquery code to display the corresponding section of category in dropdown when I select category in another dropdown.

Comment: And what is your current result?

Comment: In my html, in Jquery I tried to get the id of category. I can display it like a table format. I don't know how to display it in dependent drop down using Jquery. Please guide me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: I have to complete it before 11.30. Please help to proceed

Comment: I have to complete it before 11.30.. please guide me